# Zed's Dance: Disarray and Cabaret

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story, english

All this talk about my friends and I... it's about time I announced myself for a change!

I'm kinda nervous about this because — let's face it — I'm an odd-ball. Take, for example, the fact I usually do this special ice-breaker to... well, y'know; it's a bit of a production, or should I say "performance".

To start off, I do a dance of sorts that's quite complex and requires deft skills to pull off properly. The problem is, I seemed to have misplaced my notes regarding some of the most important steps (it's been a *looong* while since I've last shown off my moves, so forgive me if I'm a bit rusty). I need these steps because they're critical to spelling out a hidden message when they are understood by the whole performance; perhaps **you** could help me figure out what's missing — and perhaps discover the hidden message at the same time?

This is what I have so far: some general instructions, which I wrote out on a big sheet of parchment paper, and several smaller strips of paper which were supposed to jog my memory if I ever lost part of the instructions (A fat lot of good that did for me!).

Here's the main instructions:

$
\tiny\begin{array}{c}
    1  \\
    2  \\
    3  \\
    4  \\
    5  \\
    6  \\
    7  \\
    8  \\
    9  \\
    10 \\
    11 \\
    12 \\
    13 \\
    14 \\
\end{array}
\tiny\left[
{
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
    \infty  & 15    & 5     & {■}  & {-4}  & 7     & 17
    & 1     & 4     & 10    & 6     & 11    & {-7}  & 18    \\
    \infty  & 0     & {-10} & {-18} & {-19} & {■}  & 2
    & {-14} & {-11} & {-5}  & {-9}  & {-4}  & {-22} & 3     \\
    \infty  & 10    & 0     & {■}  & {-9}  & 2     & {■}
    & {-4}  & {-1}  & 5     & 1     & 6     & {-12} & 13    \\
    \infty  & 18    & 8     & 0     & {■}  & 10    & 20
    & {■}  & {■}  & 13    & 9     & 14    & {-4}  & 21    \\
   {■}     & 19    & {■}  & 1     & 0     & 11    & 21
    & 5     & 8     & 14    & 10    & 15    & {-3}  & 22    \\
    \infty  & {■}  & {-2}  & {-10} & {-11} & 0     & 10
    & {-6}  & {-3}  & {■}  & {-1}  & 4     & {-14} & 11    \\
    \infty  & {-2}  & {-12} & {-20} & {-21} & {-10} & 0
    & {-16} & {-13} & {-7}  & {■}  & {-6}  & {-24} & 1     \\
    \infty  & 14    & 4     & {-4}  & {-5}  & 6     & 16
    & 0     & 3     & 9     & 5     & {■}  & {-8}  & 17    \\
    \infty  & 11    & 1     & {-7}  & {■}  & {■}   & 13
    & {-3}  & {■}  & 6     & 2     & 7     & {-11} & 14    \\
    \infty  & 5     & {-5}  & {-13} & {-14} & {-3}  & 7
    & {-9}  & {■}  & 0     & {-4}  & 1     & {-17} & 8     \\
    \infty  & 9     & {-1}  & {-9}  & {-10} & 1     & 11
    & {-5}  & {-2}  & 4     & 0     & 5     & {■} & 12    \\
    \infty  & 4     & {-6}  & {-14} & {-15} & {-4}  & 6
    & {-10} & {-7}  & {-1}  & {-5}  & 0     & {-18} & {■}     \\
    \infty  & 22    & {■}  & 4     & 3     & 14    & 24
    & 8     & 11    & 17    & 13    & 18    & 0     & 25    \\
    \infty  & {-3}  & {-13} & {■}  & {-22} & {-11} & {-1}
    & {-17} & {-14} & {-8}  & {-12} & {-7}  & {-25} & 0     \\
\end{array}
}
\right]
$

And here are some of the scraps I've managed to pull together (for the time being):

> Don't let them fool you; Pink Floyd is your favorite method actor.

> Whether you're unlucky at first or you start at the end, you'll soon realize you were just off by one.

> Remember how to read it like the Wachowskis, but don't build it that way.

---

So, you see, I really need your help; otherwise, I'm afraid I can't properly introduce myself.

> The solution to this puzzle is not so much finding the missing steps, but rather the secret message found by discovering these steps. That being said, the final solution is a short phrase or sentence.

---

**HINTS**:

> After all this time, I only managed to find one other scrap of paper. It reads:
>
> ```
> Ask your buddy Carl; he'll have a thing or two
> to tell you about his big brother Marko
> ```